# Spring AOP Exception Polymorphism

Tags: java, spring, inheritance, aop, spring-aop

I have a problem.

Namely: I'm using spring aop to handle exceptions. Some of them are my exceptions that are being thrown in case of corrupted data delivered by outside vendor. I handle them in aspects pointed to certain type. Such as this one.

```
@AfterThrowing(
    pointcut =
      "execution(*myClass.myDataProcessingMethod(..))",
    throwing = "ex"
  )
public void myAspectMethod(MyException ex) {
...
}
```

But when something bad happends  in my data processing job, and it isn't faulty data but bug in my logic, I want to be informed on instance. So i have a second aspect.

```
@AfterThrowing(
    pointcut =
      "execution(*myClass.myDataProcessingMethod(..))",
    throwing = "ex"
  )
public void myAspectMethod(Exception ex) {
  extraInformingService.informAdamAtOnce("shitjustgotreal");
}
```

But when MyException is thrown both aspects are fired because MyException is instance of Exception to.

Is there a way to fire only the method that points to MyException ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest, albeit not very elegant version is this:

```
@AfterThrowing(
    pointcut =
      "execution(*myClass.myDataProcessingMethod(..))",
    throwing = "ex"
  )
public void myAspectMethod(Exception ex) {
  if(!ex instanceof Myexception){
      extraInformingService.informAdamAtOnce("shitjustgotreal");
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes i thought about that but since there is lots of "my" exceptions it will grow from "not very elegant" to unacceptable. Thanks anyways :-)

Comment: But maybe if I create abstract class that will be base of inheritance for all "my" exceptions it will end on only one if statement. Thanks^2 :D